# How do I create an RSS feed for Drupal?

Tags: drupal, rss, drupal-7, blogs

I have a blog in Drupal 7, and I'd like to create a RSS feed.

How do I create it?

Comment: Question is in the head and you've seen I'm sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Blog module that comes with Drupal 7 already implements a RSS feed at http://example.com/blog/feed, and `http://example.com/blog/<user id>/feed`.

If you are not using the Blog module, but you have a view done by the Views module showing a list of nodes, you can add a feed adding a new display.

[image: screenshot]